# UIScrollView changes contentOffset when I update contentInset

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

`UIScrollView` is pinned to controller's view edges.

On `UIKeyboardWillShow` I increase `contentInsets` bottom value by adding keyboard height. When animation is finished content is scrolled a little in upper direction.

```
if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
    let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double ?? 0.3
    self.formContainer.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.rowPadding, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height + self.navigator.frame.height + 10, right: 0)
    self.navigatorBottom.constant = -keyboardSize.height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to disable content scrolling here?

Comment: If you are moving your scrollview upper side with constraint  still  you need to set contentInset ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I'm not sure if I can move the scrollview itself upper as I need its entire content to be visible when scroll. I've also tried to change bottom constraint of the scrollview but it causes the same behaviour

Comment: tried to change to **UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey**

Comment: @Sh_Khan thanks! I've deal worked with this property before. I can't figure out how to use it here.

Answer (score 0):

Save `contentOffset` of `UIScrollView` before starting animation and set saved value to `contentOffset` in animation `completionHandler`

Looks like this:

```
if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
    let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double ?? 0.3
    let currentContentOffset = self.formContainer.contentOffset.y //assume your scrollView scrolls vertically
    self.formContainer.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.rowPadding, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height + self.navigator.frame.height + 10, right: 0)
    self.navigatorBottom.constant = -keyboardSize.height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { _ in
        self.formContainer.contentOffset.y = currentContentOffset
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that it doesn't work in my case. As if contentOffset is changes after completion block. `contentOffset` changes with animation of its own, maybe it causes this problem